# I am not able to update products in Shopify Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, shopify

I want update Products variant but the following code is not working:

```
$shopify = shopify\client($store, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, $access_token);

$product_array = array(
                        'id'    => 37247835908, 
                        'price' => "75.00"
                    ); 

$put = $shopify('PUT', '/admin/products/632910392.json',array(),$product_array); 
print_r($put);
```

if anyone have answer to this question then reply me thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answer of this question:

```
$shopify = shopify\client($store, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, $access_token);

$product_array = array(
                        'id'    => 37247835908, 
                        'price' => "75.00"
                    ); 

$put = $shopify('PUT', '/admin/products/632910392.json',array(),$product_array); 
print_r($put);
```

I have replace above put request like below and get the solution:

```
$product_array = array(
        'variant'=>array(               
        'id'=>#{id},
        'price'=>15.00

));

$put = $shopify('PUT /admin/variants/#{id}.json',array(),$product_array);
```

And I have successfully updated price of variant.